# What did Koui (Qiaoyi) see at the very end of the anime?

Tags: cheating-craft

At the very end of episode 12 of the anime, Koui (Qiaoyi) tails Mumei (Muming) as he goes to meet up with Shuu (Guanyu), presumably in hopes of acquiring more fuel for her curious fantasies. Then, she sees something that leads her to emit a tremendous shriek. The show abruptly ends at this point.

What did she see?

(Or, if this is unanswerable because the anime has diverged too much from the source material, that would be good to know too.)

Comment: This was asked approximately four years ago, but the answer is that it's unanswerable, because the anime diverged like you said. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find anything from the directors on it either.